# Save GIT Credentials using Git Credential Manager for Windows - Not working

Tags: git, ssh, git-credential-winstore

I would like my SSH passwords to be remembered automatically when running git pull/push on windows.

I have installed the Microsoft - Git Credential Manager for Windows

The Git Credential Manager is not Working

**Environment**

- git version 2.6.2.windows.1 loaded from here https://git-scm.com/download/win
- OpenSSH_3.8.1p1
- https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows

[image: My Environment]
[image: Steps I took]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is no magic because the credential helper is for storing *https* credentials, not ssh passphrase ones for private keys.

Try an ssh agent, as described in "[Working with SSH key passphrases](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases/)".
Note that is ssh is asking you for a *password* (not a passphrase), that also could be because your ssh public key is not [properly registered on the remote site](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/#step-4-add-your-ssh-key-to-your-account) (and it falls back to username/password way of authentication)

Comment: Thanks for the insight

Comment: This is correct, the git-credential-manager does not (yet) support storing your SSH credentials and is currently only intended for HTTPS authentication.

Comment: I decided to just use the HTTPS remote url's instead of SSH

Comment: @DavidCruwys - "Note that is ssh is asking you for a _password_ (not a passphrase)" -- I'm having this same problem, and the prompt I get over and over is "Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/Scott/.ssh/ed25519'. You're saying that's **not** SSH asking for the passphrase?

Comment: @ScottSmith passphrase means SSH. And ssh-agent to cache it.